# How do I split a line via a delimiter?

Tags: r, regex, split, delimiter

I have a dataframe.

```
[1]  Question  1. What is your name? Question  2. Where do you live? Question  3. ~~~
[2]  Question  1. What are your hobbies? Question  2. What is your school? Question  3. ~~~
```

I want to split the lines with "question  " as the delimiter. Can I solve this?

Result :

```
[1] Question  1. What is your name?
[2] Question  2. Where do you live?
[3] Question  3. ~~~
[4] Question  1. What are your hobbies?
[5] Question  2. What is your school?
[6] Question  3. ~~~
```

Comment: strsplit('What is your name? Question  2. Where do you live? Question  3. ~~~', 'Question')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `strsplit` and lookarounds, `trimws` afterwards.

```
strsplit(x, '(?<=\\s)(?=Question)', perl=TRUE) |> lapply(trimws)
# [[1]]
# [1] "Question  1. What is your name?" "Question  2. Where do you live?" "Question  3.  How old are you?" 
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "Question  1. What are your hobbies?"  "Question  2. What is your school?"   
# [3] "Question  3.  What are your hobbies?"
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- c('Question  1. What is your name? Question  2. Where do you live? Question  3.  How old are you?',
       'Question  1. What are your hobbies? Question  2. What is your school? Question  3.  What are your hobbies?')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-line solution using `stringr::str_split`. Use `unlist` to unlist.

```r
str_split(x, "(?<=.)(?=Question)")

[[1]]
[1] "Question  1. What is your name? " "Question  2. Where do you live? "
[3] "Question  3.  ~~~~"              

[[2]]
[1] "Question  1. What are your hobbies? " "Question  2. What is your school? "  
[3] "Question  3.  ~~~~"
```

data

```r
x <- c('Question  1. What is your name? Question  2. Where do you live? Question  3.  ~~~~',
       'Question  1. What are your hobbies? Question  2. What is your school? Question  3.  ~~~~')
```